# In Javafx 2, how to always draw something on top?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

I am using javafx 2.2. I have an circle object which moves as the mouse moves. However, there are new objects on the scene. I want to position this object always on top of the others.

With OPENGL, you just draw this circle LAST in each frame in the rendering loop, but with JavaFX, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Most of the time just use `Node.toFront()`*

Invoke [node.toFront()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#toFront%28%29) on starting to drag the node.

The drawing order of a node is determined by the node's position in the node's parent's `ObservableList` of children. `node.toFront()` will move the node to the end of the parent's child list so that it will be the last thing rendered for that parent.

Beware that for some layout types (such as `HBox`), the order of the node in the parent's child list also determine's the nodes layout position in the list as well as the node's rendering order.

*For 3D work alter z order*

If you are doing 3D work, then adjusting the z-coordinate of the node can also place the node on top of other nodes.

*For cross parent dragging use a stack*

If you want to drag the node out of it's parent and into another parent, then you could make the root of the scene a stack, remove the node from it's initial parent, place it at the top of the scene stack, drag it to it's new parent, and on drag finished, remove the node from the scene stack and place it into the appropriate position in it's new parent's child list.